# Customizing names of auxiliary file: safe practices?

Tags: best-practices, package-writing, auxiliary-files

I maintain a package ([`morewrites`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/morewrites/)) which requires a temporary auxiliary file to function (written and read right away).  This auxiliary file is currently named `\jobname.mw`, and a user has asked me to allow customization because this extension conflicts with some other tool.

My first idea is to provide an interface of the form `\morewritessetup{file=...}` where `...` is replaced by the name the user wants to use.

However, I am worried about users doing `\morewritessetup{file=\jobname}` by mistake.  When my code then writes to the file `\jobname`, it will clobber the source file `\jobname.tex` and the user will be very unhappy.  This is actually a bigger problem: it would be best to make sure that I am not destroying any of the user's pre-existing files.  Unfortunately, I cannot simply check that the file is new before writing it, since that will only be the case the very first time TeX is run on the file.

What is a safe approach?

Comment: Not entirely safe but what about a file name like `\jobname-mw.aux`?

Comment: Why not only allow a customisable extension instead of the whole name?

Comment: Or just check if the given one is `\jobname`, and, in that case, throw an error.

Comment: We had recently a case when `\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}` destroyed a user's bibliographic database because the `filecontents` package was loaded. In my `gmp` package I use `\jobname+mp<number>`, but of course this still might overwrite a preexisting file. In `imakeidx` I use the standard `.ind` extension, so the problem is more limited. Maybe checking if the file starts with some prescribed bytes? If it does, you can assume it has been written in a previous run.

Comment: @egreg I like your last idea, with a first line such as `%% File generated by the TeX package morewrites`.

Comment: @egreg: I like the idea too. A boolean that checks the first line for a message would very useful.

Comment: @egreg would you care to answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TeX by itself doesn't make any check when it's requested to start writing a file. This can have undesired consequences.

For example, using `\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}` along with `\usepackage{filecontents}` caused the overwriting of a preexisting bibliographic database with the same name. On an operating system I won't name, doing `\include{file.tex}` can lead to destruction of `file.tex` because the system doesn't allow multiple periods in a file name and, when TeX tries to write on `file.tex.aux`, the OS discards the second extension.

The first problem is solved by *avoiding* `\usepackage{filecontents}` unless one is sure it won't overwrite necessary files. The second problem might be solved by fixing `\include` so that it stops when the argument contains the `.tex` extension (which shouldn't be used anyway, in this case).

The problem arises whenever an auxiliary file is being written out. In my `gmp` package, the file names used are `\jobname+mp<number>` that should be safe enough; for `imakeidx` I rely on the `.idx`, `.ind` and `.ilg` extensions.

A possible solution for your problem is looking at the first lines of the file that will be overwritten, in case it already exists. If they match a certain pattern, you can be almost certain the file has been created by your package on a previous run.

Comment: At the end of the day, since I do not need the file to keep information between runs, I decided only use the file if it is empty, and empty it every time I am done using it.